# combining Math.max.apply and Math.min.apply together?

Tags: javascript

This is simple program where user enters string of different numbers and I need to find biggest and smallest number  of those entered. I want to keep code as simple as possible. It works fine like this this with two alerts one for smallest and another for biggest number:

```
var x = prompt("Enter 5 numbers : x, x, x, x, x");
x = x.split(",");
window.alert(Math.max.apply(Math, x));
window.alert(Math.min.apply(Math, x));
```

but I was wondering if there is a way to combine Math.max.apply and Math.min.apply into one line of code to make it show min and max numbers  from the string together ?

Comment: like `alert(Math.max.apply(Math, x) + ' ' + Math.min.apply(Math, x))`?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just define a string beforehand?

```js
const nums = prompt("Enter 5 numbers : x, x, x, x, x").split(",");
const outputStr = `Max: ${Math.max.apply(Math, nums)}
Min: ${Math.min.apply(Math, nums)}`;
window.alert(outputStr);
```

That's not even necessary though, you can shove it all into `alert` if you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

#### Template literals

> Template literals are string literals allowing embedded expressions. You can use multi-line strings and string interpolation features with them. They were called "template strings" in prior editions of the ES2015 specification.

```js
// Get the requred numbers
// use Array.split to convert them to an array so you will be able to use
// Math.max.apply
var input = prompt("Enter 5 numbers : x, x, x, x, x").split(',');

// Using ES6 templates you can use the '`' sign to combine the input 
// into a shorter string. In order to print values inside the template
// literal, you simply use the ${...} syntax
const numbers = `${Math.max.apply(Math, nums)}, ${Math.min.apply(Math, nums)}`;

console.log(numbers);
```